# Импорт пакета в GO обновляет версии других зависимостей

Tags: golang

У меня есть 2 проекта я использую клиент первого в другом как зависимость.
При импорте клиента почему-то меняются версии большого количества пакетов в go.mod

По типу
github.com/rs/zerolog v1.29.1 => v1.31.0
...

Почему это происходит? Это поведение возникает только после добавления именно этой зависимости

Comment: Как вы импортируете - через `go mod tidy` или `go get`?

Comment: go mod tidy хотя пробовал по разному

Comment: go mod tidy обновляет все зависимости. go get добавляет только одну зависимость .